# Is it possible to stream during a conversion? - FFMPEG

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I'm wondering if it is possible to stream video while the video is being generated through conversion.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your copy of FFmpeg includes something like `rtmp` amongst the protocols listed with `ffmpeg -protocols` you should be able to do this using the [`split`](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#split) video filter.  The whole command will look something like:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 <video options> -filter split rtmp://server[:port][/app] out.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

well use the url you want to stream to (be it udp or rtmp) as output instead to output to a file.

To do both , you ll need to use pipe